# Create an applescript from a perl and a ruby script?

Tags: applescript, fasta

I download protein sequences from http://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/FLU/Database/nph-select.cgi#mainform, which are downloaded with filename FASTA.FA. For each protein in the file, it includes one describing row, and then protein sequence separated with a new row after each 70 characters.

Example:

>CAA47401 B/Yamagata/16/88 1988// NA
MLPSTIQTLTLFLTSGGVLLSLYVSASLSYLLYSDILLKFSPTEITAPKVPLDCANASNVQAVNRSATKG
MTLLLSEPEWTYPRLSCQGSTFQKALLISPHRFGESRGNSAPLIIREPFIACGPKECKHFALTHYAAQPG
>AAB26739 Influenza B virus 1973// NA
MLPSTIQTLTLFLTSGGVLLSLYVSASLSYLLYSDILLKFSPTKITAPTMSLDCANVSNVQAVNRSATKE
DVPCIGIEMVHDGGKETWHSAATAIYCLMGSGQLLWDIVTGVAMAL

I have a ruby script that converts this to a file that fits Excel better, where the first line gets one cell and the entire protein sequence gets one another cell (perl makes a tab between and Excel puts stuff separated with tab in a new cell).

This is my script:

```
ruby -e 'first_line = true; while line = STDIN.gets; line.chomp!; 
if line =~ /^>/; puts unless first_line; print line[1..-1]; print "\t"; 
else; print line; end; first_line = false; end; puts' < ~/Downloads/FASTA.fa > ~/Downloads/Sequences.xls
```

On the website where I download the files you can change how the first line should be formatted, and I include a "+" between each description, and I then have a perl script that converts + to tab (some descriptions have a space within it, so I cant use space as a separator).

```
perl -p -i -e "s/\+/\t/g" ~/Downloads/Sequences.xls
```

These two hacks successfully creates a nice excel file for me, and I have made an Automator program from these two scripts that sits in my dock.

However, now my group wants me to create an applescript out of this. If I have understood this correctly, it's not as simple as just typing "do shell script" and then paste the script, but you have to format the actual script itself so that applescript understands it. Could anyone please help me in creating this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you should make the ruby script into a proper `.rb` file, and while you're at it, use Ruby to do the tab-replacement (or use the [Spreadsheet gem](http://spreadsheet.ch/), if you want fancier Excel output, though that might require some setup on other people's computers). Or do it all in Perl instead. Just to save you the trouble of spinning up two runtimes for such trivial search/replace stuff. For that matter you can do it all in `sed`, I'm sure.

Anyway, once you have the script as a file, you can make a new script in AppleScript Editor and save it as a *script bundle*. Then you can include the scripts "inside" your AppleScript. That way, you know where the scripts are, and they're much, much easier to edit if need be. Then you can use `do shell script` to invoke the script with the proper arguments. Simplified example:

```
-- get script path
set rb to POSIX path of (path to me) & "Contents/Resources/Scripts/convert.rb"

-- run script
do shell script "ruby '" & rb & "' < inputfile.fa > outputfile.xls"
```

If you want, you can even get some drag-and-drop conversion going, instead of hard-coding a path to `~/Downloads/FASTA.fa` (if someone forgets to move/delete an old download, it'll keep converting that one, and writing over the same xls, since a new download would be "FASTA-1.fa" or something, so avoid hard-coded paths if you can)